# How to add dropdown list to HTML table cell

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML table and a button that allow user to add a new column. Right now user able to add new column when pressing "add". For example a new column `Group1` is added after user press on `add column`.

[image]

**Question**: How can I insert a dropdownlist for every new added column cell instead of `1`, `2`..? Other than that, it should allow user to select and deselect their option.

**Expected Output**:

[image]

```js
let groupNum = 1;
const tableEl = document.getElementById('member_table');

// append column to the HTML table
function appendColumn() {

  // open loop for each row and append cell
  for (let i = 0; i < tableEl.rows.length; i++) {
    createCell(tableEl.rows[i].insertCell(tableEl.rows[i].cells.length), i, 'col');
  }

  tableEl.rows[0].querySelector('td:last-child').textContent = 'Group' + groupNum;
  groupNum++;
}

// create DIV element and append to the table cell
function createCell(cell, text, style) {
  var div = document.createElement('div'), // create DIV element
    txt = document.createTextNode(text); // create text node
  div.appendChild(txt); // append text node to the DIV
  div.setAttribute('class', style); // set DIV class attribute
  div.setAttribute('className', style); // set DIV class attribute for IE (?!)
  cell.appendChild(div); // append DIV to the table cell
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table id="member_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="javascript:appendColumn()">Add column</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to refactor your function this way:

```js
let groupNum = 1;
const tableEl = document.getElementById('member_table');

// append column to the HTML table
function appendColumn(template, type = "text") {

  // open loop for each row and append cell
  for (let i = 0; i < tableEl.rows.length; i++) {
    createCell(tableEl.rows[i].insertCell(tableEl.rows[i].cells.length), template ? template : i, 'col', type);
  }

  tableEl.rows[0].querySelector('td:last-child').textContent = 'Group' + groupNum;
  groupNum++;
}

// create DIV element and append to the table cell
function createCell(cell, content, style, type="text") {
  var div = document.createElement('div'), // create DIV element
    txt = document.createElement(type); // create text node
    txt.innerHTML = content;
  div.appendChild(txt); // append text node to the DIV
  div.setAttribute('class', style); // set DIV class attribute
  div.setAttribute('className', style); // set DIV class attribute for IE (?!)
  cell.appendChild(div); // append DIV to the table cell
}

appendColumn(`
        <option value="1">ABC</option>
        <option value="2">DEF</option>
        <option value="3">GHI</option>
`, 'select');
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table id="member_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="javascript:appendColumn()">Add column</button>
```

You might want further refactoring to support more stuff, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: Hi thanks for ur reply, but this method wont work if user press on add group right? The new added column will show `undefined`

Comment: @terry5546 basically you will need to call `createElement` or `createTextNode`, depending on the input. In my answer I was making a proof-of-concept.

Comment: @terry5546 edited my answer to maintain your old feature. Please test it again.